# Product prices with custom decimals for a product category in WooCommerce cart and checkout too

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, decimal, price

I have tried *"[Custom decimals in WooCommerce product prices for a product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424141/custom-decimals-in-woocommerce-product-prices-for-a-product-category/45425441#45425441)"* answer code that works well on product pages, but not in cart and checkout pages.

Does anybody have an idea on how to display prices with custom decimals in cart and checkout pages too for a specific product category?

Any track is appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea, but this post maybe can help to have a solutions https://www.skyverge.com/blog/change-woocommerce-price-display/