# WooCommerce Cart Not Showing Pricing On Small Decimals Correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some products where the pricing needs to be shown to 8 decimal places, for example, price per unit is 0.00000214.

I've tried adding a filter but it's just showing the value 0.00000000

Here's what I have:

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) 
{ 
    $formattedNum = number_format((float) $price, 8); 
    return $formattedNum;
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
```

Thank you

Comment: The `number_format` is returning `string`. I smell a problem here...

Comment: Hmm, could I do `return floatval($formattedNum);`?

Comment: I have so many questions regarding this. While you probably could do this, how am I expected to pay you 0.00000214? :)

Comment: @PavelJanicek It's just for display, there is a minimum quantity set on purchases of a dollar or more. It's for in game currency. If I do `return floatval($formattedNum);` It shows 0 on the price.

Comment: Have look at this. Is it any helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424141/custom-decimals-in-woocommerce-product-prices-for-a-product-category

Comment: That works for table prices, but not for cart pricing

Comment: Actually I think I can modify it to do what I want, testing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that $price is returning the already formatted value. I needed to get the raw price.

This is the working solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
function change_cart_item_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key )
{
    if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() )
    {
        $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'] );
    } else
    {
        $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'] );
    }

    $price =  number_format($product_price,8);

    return floatval($price);
}
```